# Refactoring If Statements For Better Readability

Tags: java, refactoring, readability, negation

I'm currently working on a project that will diminish a class that being used by other several classes.

```
if(condition_A)
{
     doSomething();
}
else if(condition_B)
{
     classToBeRemoved();
}
else
{
     doAnother();
}
```

The first solution that came up to me is to negate the condition of the if-else statement that will be modified.

```
if(condition_A)
{
     doSomething();
}
else if(!condition_B)
{
     doAnother();
}
```

This method of refactoring do not affect the functionality of the code but sometimes if the condition is too long, it affects the readability of the code.

Is there another way that will maintain the readability of the code other than negating the condition?

Comment: I'd say your first solution is the best readable. Why do you want to make it 'more readable'?

Comment: Your two blocks of code do different things. Does `classToBeRemoved()`  need to be called, or not?

Comment: @RobertvanderSpek the code is for the whole team so it should easily by other people.

Comment: @khelwood the goal is to diminished that class for the whole project because it is not needed anymore.

Comment: This question is primarily opinionated. It's also quite dependent on the specific case, as well as the coding conventions used in your project.

Comment: I find `switch` more readable

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with functions, vaguely like:

```
List<BooleanSupplier> actions = new ArrayList<>();
actions.add(() -> {
    if (!condition_A) {
        return false;
    }
    doSomething();
    return true;
});
actions.add(this::canDoSomething);

if (!actions.stream().anyMatch(p::get)) {
    doAnother();
}
```

I took the liberty to abstract condition+action into a predicate, instead of using a Pair or such.

This is uglier, but could **decouple** things, as now the add's can come from *outside* the class, defining a `public void addAction(BooleanSupplier action)`.

Though probably a parameter is needed to provide a data context (`Predicate<?>`).